# using parallelize to create a key/value pair RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The spark [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=sparkcontext#pyspark.SparkContext.parallelize) provide the following definition for creating an RDD using parallelize:

> parallelize(c, numSlices=None)
>
> Distribute a local Python collection to form an RDD. Using xrange is
>   recommended if the input represents a range for performance.
>
> ```
> >>> sc.parallelize([0, 2, 3, 4, 6], 5).glom().collect()
> [[0], [2], [3], [4], [6]]
> >>> sc.parallelize(xrange(0, 6, 2), 5).glom().collect()
> [[], [0], [], [2], [4]]
> ```

I would like to create a key/value pair RDD, how can I do this with parallelize?  Example output RDD:

```
key    |  value
-------+-------
panda  |  0
pink   |  3
pirate |  3
panda  |  1
pink   |  4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sc.parallelize([("panda", 0), ("pink", 3)])
```

Comment: I should have realised it would have been just an array of tuples!  Anyway thanks!

Comment: No problem! It could be list of lists from two elements as well, tuples just look more natural. `sc.parallelize([["panda", 0], ["pink", 3]]).countByKey()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

sc.parallelize(Seq(("panda", 0), ("pink", 3)))